# Issue with date checking

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

In Apex app I've a region called Person on a page. Inside a region there is a masked date picker. I have a task to validate the date of birth. So, the date of birth could not be less 1900 year. In "Conditions" section i'd been trying to write an pl/sql expression:

```
TRUNC(TO_DATE(:P1002_CONTR_BIRTH_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY')) > TO_DATE('01.01.1900', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a recognised error message. What happens? Do you get an error, or wrong results? What data type is `P1002_CONTR_BIRTH_DATE`? If it's already a date then you don't need to pass it in to `to_date()`, and if you do it's likely to not do what you want...

Comment: note, the TRUNC is superfluous in this case

Answer (score 1):

You put it to wrong place - "Condition" is used to decide whether an item will (or will not) be rendered on the screen.

Validation should be put into ... well, ***validation*** (obviously).

- right-click the P1002_CONTR_BIRTH_DATE date picker item
- choose "Create Validation"
- set its type to "PL/SQL function (returning error text)
- use such a code (presuming that you set the date picker format mask to MM-DD-YYYY):

---

```
if to_date(:P1002_CONTR_BIRTH_DATE, 'mm-dd-yyyy') < date '1900-01-01' then
   return ('Error - can not set it to before 01-01-1900');
end if;
```

- set it to fire when SUBMIT button is pressed

**Alternatively** (and way simpler) would be to open date picker item's property palette, navigate to its "Minimum date" property and put (for example) `-120y` in there which will allow dates that are higher than `sysdate - 120 years` (today, Apex would raise the

> Birth date is less than specified minimum date 04-15-1898'

which isn't exactly "1900", but - you can easily calculate it, right? Also, -120y is somewhat more flexible than fixed year 1900.

Now you have two options, pick the one that suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

TO_DATE() method is to convert a string to date, the string format should be the same as format_mask.

`TRUNC(TO_DATE(:P1002_CONTR_BIRTH_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY')) > TO_DATE('01-01-1900', 'MM-DD-YYYY')`

or

`TRUNC(TO_DATE(:P1002_CONTR_BIRTH_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY')) > TO_DATE('01.01.1900', 'MM.DD.YYYY')`

and also make sure `:P1002_CONTR_BIRTH_DATE` is also the same as format.

For [detail](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Comment: Oracle is flexible about this by default, often unhelpfully so; it will happily swap period and dashes when converting a string to a date.